# TimerCallback function not getting hit in deployed environment C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, callback, chatbot

I have a Microsoft Chatbot C# code,which has a TimerCallback function, which runs after some inactive time by user. This function gets hit when running code locally, but the same function does not get hit, when deployed on Azure environment.

Appologies for too much logging lines in the code, it was just to verify that function gets hit on deployed environment or not.

Here is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Lebara.Crm.Bot.Core.Data;
using Lebara.Crm.Bot.Core.ServiceContracts;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Distributed;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Lebara.Crm.Bot.Services
{
    public class ChatSessionTimeoutMiddleware : ActivityHandler, IMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;
        private readonly string _cachekey;
        private readonly BotOptions _botOptions;
        private readonly ISystemMessageSender _systemMessageSender;
        private readonly CustomConversationStateAccessors _customConversationStateAccessors;
        private readonly ITelemetryManager _telemetryManager;
        private readonly ISessionHandler _sessionHandler;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Timer> _sessionTimers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Timer>();
        private readonly IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter _adapter;
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;
        private string ObjectKey;
        private readonly TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        private readonly ILogger<ChatSessionTimeoutMiddleware> _logger;

        //  Timer related variables, made global, to avoid collected by Garbage Collector as they were created in memory previously.
        private Timer _warningTimer = null;
        private Timer _warningTimerGCIssue = null;
        private Timer _timer = null;
        private Timer _timerGCIssue = null;

        public ChatSessionTimeoutMiddleware(
            IDistributedCache distributedCache,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IOptions<BotOptions> options,
            ISystemMessageSender systemMessageSender,
            CustomConversationStateAccessors customConversationStateAccessors,
            ITelemetryManager telemetryManager,
            ISessionHandler sessionHandler,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter,
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences,
            ILogger<ChatSessionTimeoutMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _cachekey = $"{configuration["RedisCachingRoot"]}session-timeout:";
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
            _botOptions = options.Value;
            _systemMessageSender = systemMessageSender;
            _customConversationStateAccessors = customConversationStateAccessors;
            _telemetryManager = telemetryManager;
            _sessionHandler = sessionHandler;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _adapter = adapter;
            _conversationReferences = conversationReferences;
            _appId = configuration["MicrosoftAppId"] ?? string.Empty;
            _logger = logger;

        }

        private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity)
        {
            var conversationReference = activity.GetConversationReference();
            _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(conversationReference.User.Id, conversationReference, (key, newValue) => conversationReference);
        }

        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("chat session timeout middleware");
            //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - OnTurnAsync");
            //telemetry.TrackTrace("ChatSessionMiddleware - OnTurnAsync", SeverityLevel.Warning, null);
            var customConversationState = await _customConversationStateAccessors.CustomConversationState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CustomConversationState());
            var hasChatSessionRunning = await _sessionHandler.HasRunningSessionAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);

            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text)
                && !hasChatSessionRunning)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("chatsessiontimeout OnTurnAsync if statement");
                var key = _cachekey + turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id;
                _logger.LogDebug($"Key {key}");
                var warningKey = "warning_" + key;
                _logger.LogDebug($"WarningKey {warningKey}");
                var period = _botOptions.InactivityPeriod;
                _logger.LogDebug($"chatsessiontimeout period {period}");
                var warningPeriod = _botOptions.WarningInactivityPeriod;
                _logger.LogDebug($"chatsessiontimeout warningPeriod {warningPeriod}");
                var cacheOptions = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
                {
                    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = period.Add(period)
                };
                _logger.LogDebug($"cacheOptions {cacheOptions}");
                AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);

                await _distributedCache.SetStringAsync(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now.Add(period)), cacheOptions);
                await _distributedCache.SetStringAsync(warningKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now.Add(warningPeriod)), cacheOptions);

                var timerPeriod = period.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                var warningTimePeriod = warningPeriod.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                _warningTimer = null;
                _warningTimerGCIssue = null;
                _sessionTimers.TryGetValue(warningKey, out _warningTimer);
                _logger.LogDebug($"warningTimer {_warningTimer}");
                if (_warningTimer == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("warningTimer is null");

                    _warningTimerGCIssue = new Timer(new TimerCallback(WarningCallback), (warningKey, turnContext), warningTimePeriod, warningTimePeriod);

                    _warningTimer = _sessionTimers.GetOrAdd(warningKey, _warningTimerGCIssue);
                }

                _timer = null;
                _timerGCIssue = null;
                _sessionTimers.TryGetValue(key, out _timer);
                _logger.LogDebug($"timer {_timer}");
                if (_timer == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("timer is null");
                    _logger.LogDebug($"key {key}");
                    _timerGCIssue = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Callback), (key, turnContext), timerPeriod, timerPeriod);
                    _timer = _sessionTimers.GetOrAdd(key, _timerGCIssue);
                }

                _warningTimer.Change(warningTimePeriod, warningTimePeriod);
                _logger.LogDebug("chatSessionTimeoutMiddleware timer change");
                _timer.Change(timerPeriod, timerPeriod);

            }
            _logger.LogDebug("chatSessionTimeoutMiddleware nextturn");
            await nextTurn(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        }

        private async void Callback(object target)
        {
            //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - InactivityCallback");
            _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware InactivityCallback");
            var tuple = ((string, ITurnContext))target;
            ObjectKey = tuple.Item1;
            var turnContext = tuple.Item2;

            foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware InactivityCallback for loop");
                await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, EndOfChatCallback, default(CancellationToken));
            }

        }

        private async void WarningCallback(object target)
        {
            //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - WarningCallback");
            _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware WarningCallback");
            var tuple = ((string, ITurnContext))target;
            ObjectKey = tuple.Item1;
            var turnContext = tuple.Item2;

            foreach (var conversationReference in _conversationReferences.Values)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware WarningCallback for loop");
                await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, WarningMessageCallback, default(CancellationToken));
            }

        }


        private async Task WarningMessageCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - WarningMessageCallback");
            _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware WarningMessageCallback");
            var customConversationState = await _customConversationStateAccessors.CustomConversationState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CustomConversationState());

            void DisposeTimer()
            {
                bool found = _sessionTimers.TryRemove(ObjectKey, out var timer);
                if (found)
                {
                    timer.Dispose();
                    timer = null;
                }

            }

            var json = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(ObjectKey);
            var hasChatSessionRunning = await _sessionHandler.HasRunningSessionAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);

            if (hasChatSessionRunning)
            {
                DisposeTimer();
                return;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var sessionEnd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(json);

                if (DateTime.Now >= sessionEnd)
                {
                    //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - SendingWarningMessage");
                    _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware SendingWarningMessage");
                    await _systemMessageSender.SendSystemMessage(turnContext, customConversationState, turnContext.Activity, ResourceIds.BotWarningEndOfChat);
                }
            }

            DisposeTimer();

        }

        private async Task EndOfChatCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - EndOfChatCallback");
            _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware EndOfChatCallback");
            var chatSdk = (IChatProvider)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IChatProvider));
            var customConversationState = await _customConversationStateAccessors.CustomConversationState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new CustomConversationState());

            void DisposeTimer()
            {
                bool found = _sessionTimers.TryRemove(ObjectKey, out var timer);
                if (found)
                {
                    timer.Dispose();
                    timer = null;
                }

            }

            var json = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(ObjectKey);
            var hasChatSessionRunning = await _sessionHandler.HasRunningSessionAsync(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);

            if (hasChatSessionRunning)
            {
                DisposeTimer();
                return;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var sessionEnd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(json);
                if (DateTime.Now >= sessionEnd)
                {
                    var parts = ObjectKey.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"EndTime", json },
                        {"State", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customConversationState) }
                    };

                    _telemetryManager.TrackEvent("AutomaticChatClosing", parts[parts.Length - 1], dict);

                    DisposeTimer();
                    //telemetry.TrackEvent("ChatSessionMiddleware - SendingEndOfChatMessage");
                    _logger.LogDebug("ChatSessionMiddleware SendingEndOfChatMessage");
                    await _systemMessageSender.SendSystemMessage(turnContext, customConversationState, turnContext.Activity, ResourceIds.BotAutomaticEndOfChat);
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    await chatSdk.EndChat(customConversationState.ChatContext, turnContext);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisposeTimer();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The code creating issue/ or not getting hit:

```
if (_warningTimer == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug("warningTimer is null");

                    _warningTimerGCIssue = new Timer(new TimerCallback(WarningCallback), (warningKey, turnContext), warningTimePeriod, warningTimePeriod);

                    _warningTimer = _sessionTimers.GetOrAdd(warningKey, _warningTimerGCIssue);
                }
```

the above mentioned part should call the WarningCallback function after a specific warning time, it does call it successfully while running the code locally, but does not call on deployed environment.

Comment: Do you think you could reduce the code down to a point which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Enigmativity pointed out the code, creating issue

Comment: You misunderstood my point. Could you please write a minimal amount of code that demonstrates the issue and show us only that?